# Every Cauchy sequence in $\Bbb{R}$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, cauchy-sequences

Theorem 2.5: Every Cauchy sequence in $\Bbb{R}$ converges. There exists an $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x_i \rightarrow x$.

Proof: Let $x = \sup_{n>0} \inf_{i>n} x_i$. Then
$|x − x_n| \leq \sup_{i,j\geq n} |x_i − x_j| \rightarrow 0$.

I do not understand why the inequality is true.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for advice on how to make your questions more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that $x$ is a limit point of the set $\{x_i\mid i\ge n\}$. That is, for any $n$, for any $\epsilon>0$, we can find $i\ge n$ such that $|x_i-x|<\epsilon$. It follows that the distance from $x_n$ to $x$ is no greater than $\sup_{i\ge n}|x_n-x_i|$, which of course is no greater than $\sup_{i,j\ge n}|x_i-x_j|$.

Comment: But isn’t x_i between x_n and x?

Comment: Oops, I didn't say what I meant. Edited my last sentence to fix it.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. It just seems as though the final two will always be equal to each other, and so the less than or equal to sign confused me.